# Multer not uploading the image in express app

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I have written this simple application to test multer to upload files into my server. I am trying to test this using postman where I have selected `form-data` option, added a key to my image and uploaded the image using the button next to it. The API is called correctly but the image doesn't get uploaded.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({
  dest: 'images/',
});

app.post('/uploadchq', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
  console.dir("file", req.file);
  console.dir("files", req.files);
  console.log("body", req.body);
  next();
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(9999);
console.log("listening to port", 9999);
```

Multer is creating the image directory that I have specified in the `dest` field, but `req.file` , `req.files` , `req.body` all the field are empty. I tried using `upload.single` instead of `any` with the key name as the parameter but it still doesn't work. What is the problem ?

Edit: In reply to Gaurav's comment. Here is the screen shot of postman. I have changed the key name from `chqImg` to `file` instead.
[image: Screenshot of postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I just unchecked the header field in postman which was setting the `Content-type` to `multipart/form-data` . However, I am not able to understand why it won't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        var dest = 'images/';
        cb(null, dest);
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

app.post('/uploadchq', upload.fields([{
    name: 'file'
}]), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("files", req.files.file);
    console.log("body", req.body);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. It still shows that `req.files` in line `console.log("files", req.files.file);` is undefined and there is nothing inside the image directory.

Comment: you need to sent `formData` from client which contains _file_ key and _fileobject_ as value

Comment: Yes I have done that ... still not working.. I have updated my answer with the postman screenshot.

Comment: Infact, the destination function is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Axios won't work with multer so need to use XMLHTTPRequest

```
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'url');
    request.send(formData)
```